# Buttons placed on resizer disappears when resizing on jQuery Layout Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery UI Layout plugin (layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm) in my web application.

Using 3 panels only (center, west and north), I have set the resizer to be resizable while dragging with the mouse on the west panel. **This function is on my AngularJS directive**:

```
$(element[0]).layout({
    north__resizable: false,
    closable: false,
    slidable: false,
    north: {
        spacing_open: 0,
        resizable: false,
        togglerLength_open: 0,
        togglerLength_closed: 0,
        minSize: 30,
        maxSize: 30
    },
    west: {
        spacing_open: 8,
        size: 250,
        minSize: 160,
        maxSize: 600,
        resizable: true,
        resizeWhileDragging: true
    },
    center: {
        spacing_open: 30,
        resizable: false,
        closable: false,
        slidable: false,
        resizeWhileDragging: true
    }
});
```

For design purposes, I have put an icon in the middle of the vertical resizer. **This function is on my controller's init():**

```
    _self.setResizableLayout = function() {
        $timeout(function () {
            $('.ui-layout-resizer-west').attr('ng-attr-title', "{{'drag' | translate}}");
            $('.ui-layout-resizer-west').append(
                '<span class="icon-dots-three-horizontal3" style="-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); transform: rotate(90deg); font-size: 5px; display: block; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-left: -4px; opacity: 0.6; visibility: visible!important;"></span>');
        }, 200)
    }
```

Also, there is a `:hover` and `:active` style whenever the resizer is hovered and clicked:

```
.ui-layout-resizer-west {
    border-left: 1px solid #dadee3;
    background: #f0f3f8;
    border-right: none;
    width: 8px !important;

    &:hover, &:active {
        border-right: 1px solid #dadee3;
        background: #E1EAF2;
        cursor: move !important;
        cursor: -moz-grab !important;
        cursor: -webkit-grab !important;
        border-right: 1px solid #dadee3;
    }
```

### The Problems

---

1. Whenever I click to start dragging the vertical resizer, after moving it a little bit, the icon disappears. It only appears again when the mouse button is released.
2. Whenever I drag the resizer, the `:hover` effect is lost when the cursor is not hovering the element (like when dragging the resizer to its limits and moving the cursor further, while the mouse button is still pressed down). Seems that it is ignoring the `:active` selector.

**Question:** is there any workaround so I can keep the icon always showing up and preserve the `:hover` style when dragging the resizer?

### The Answers

---

1. `display: none` did the trick.
2. Had a better look at the docs, and implemented the css class `.ui-layout-resizer-dragging` with the style I wanted when dragging the resizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hover aspect, I implemented the class `.ui-layout-resizer-dragging` on my styles with the same style as my `:hover` and `:active` selectors (maybe the last one is useless now):

```
        &:hover, &:active {
            background: #E1EAF2;
            cursor: move !important;
            cursor: -moz-grab !important;
            cursor: -webkit-grab !important;
            border-right: 1px solid #dadee3;
        }
    }
    .ui-layout-resizer-dragging { /* resizer beging 'dragging' */
        background: #E1EAF2;
        cursor: move !important;
        cursor: -moz-grab !important;
        cursor: -webkit-grab !important;
        border-right: 1px solid #dadee3;
        display: none;
    }
```

I used `display: none` on the `.ui-layout-resizer-dragging` class as seen above, so the icon is displayed when I drag the resizer.